# Does this series converge, and if so to what value?: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left\{\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \right\}\ln(2n+1)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've arrived at this series from a given sequence of terms, but now I'm at a loss as to how to proceed... How does one know which convergence test to use? This isn't a geometric series, so I don't have a handy formula to plug numbers into. And taking the limit as $x\ \to \infty$ gives me an indeterminate form of $0 \cdot \infty$.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left\{\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \right\}\ln(2n+1)$$

Comment: If you can read French, the convergence is folklore: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Bertrand Re the value of the sum, I see no reason to expect it should be a simple combination of some known constants.

Comment: After translating that page using Chrome, I still don't understand... Are you saying it should diverge? How can I prove that?

Comment: You can use that $\ln(2n+1)<\sqrt{n}$ for n sufficiently large, so $\frac{\ln(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2}<\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ for n large.

Comment: $\ln(2n+1)\ll \sqrt{n+1}$ for large enough $n$, so you can compare this to $\sum\frac{1}{(n+1)^{1.5}}$ to prove convergence.

Comment: Okay so I should do a comparison test with $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left\{\frac{1}{(n+1)^{1.5}} \right\}$  ?

Comment: Or other similar series, yes, that seems to be the easiest way.  You should be aware that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}$ will always converge if $p>1$ and will diverge for $p\leq 1$, but again, this only proves convergence.  Getting an exact value would be difficult (if even possible).

Comment: Limit comparison lets us compare to the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\ln(2n)}{(n+1)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\ln(2)}{(n+1)^2} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\ln(n)}{(n+1)^2}$. The first series clearly converges, and the second series is smaller than $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ln(n)}{n^2}$, which converges by the integral test after one application of integration by parts.

Comment: According to Wolfy, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (log(n))/n^2 = -1/6 π^2 (-12 log(A) + \gamma + log(2) + log(π))$. $A$ is the Glaisher-Kinkelin constant.

Answer (score 2):

To prove convergence:

For any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $\ln (2n+1) < n^{\epsilon}$ for all $n > n_{\varepsilon}$ for a certain $n_{\varepsilon}$ depending on $\varepsilon$ (hence the subscript)

So, let $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, then we can compare this series to $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)^{1.5}}$, which converges by the $p$-series test since $p = 1.5$ is greater than $1$.

Note that finding the exact value of a sum is often much more difficult than proving whether or not it converges. I calculated up to the $100000$th partial sum and got $S \approx 1.2713728 \dots$

Comment: Why is it that we can ignore the "+1" within the parenthesis in the denominator when using the p-series test?

Comment: And how would I deduce what the series converges to?

Comment: Note that the sum is the same as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1.5}}$, which gets rid of the +1 problem. You could also use a comparison since $\frac{1}{(n+1)^{1.5}} < \frac{1}{n^{1.5}}$. In other cases, if it is obvious enough you may heuristically argue that the +1 "doesn't really matter" in the sum.

Answer (score 2):

Use equivalents: $\;\ln(2n+1)\sim_{\infty} \ln n$, $\;(n+1)^2\sim_{\infty}n^2$, so $\,\dfrac{\ln(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2}\sim_{\infty}\dfrac{\ln n}{n^2}$, which is a convergent Bertrand's series.

*Note:* A *Bertrand's series* is a series  $\;\displaystyle\sum\limits_n\dfrac1{n^\alpha(\ln n)^\beta}$. It converges if and only if $\alpha>1$ or $\,(\alpha=1$ and $\beta>1)$. It can be proved using the *integral test*.

Comment: Hmm... We haven't discussed Bertrand's series in our class though, so I can't imagine this being how the professor wants me to go about it. Even if this is a nice, straightforward approach.

Comment: Note I gave a hint (integral test). You can apply it just in this case, or, while you're at it, check by yourself the  general case. It is not very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

To show that the series converges, notice that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\log(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2}
&\le\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\log(2n+2)}{(n+1)^2}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log(2n)}{n^2}\\
&=\log(2)\color{#00A000}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}}+\color{#C00000}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log(n)}{n^2}}\\
\end{align}
$$
We can show that both of these sums converges by the integral test. Integrating by parts yields
$$
\begin{align}
\color{#C00000}{\int_1^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x}
&=-\int_1^\infty\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}\frac1x\\
&=\int_1^\infty\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}\log(x)\\
&=\color{#00A000}{\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\[6pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$
Using the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula to $O\!\left(\log(n)n^{-21}\right)$ and summing to $n=100$, we get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\log(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2}\doteq1.271388320211200139286593230121
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The very similar series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\ln(2n+\color{red}2)}{(n+1)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\ln(n+1)+\ln(2)}{(n+1)^2}=-\zeta'(2)+\ln(2)\zeta(2).$$

A correction can be brought with

$$\ln\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\right)=\ln\left(1-\frac1{2n+2}\right)=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k(2n+2)^k},$$
leading to
$$-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\zeta(k+2)}{2^kk}.$$

Comment: What is that strange looking symbol you're using there?

Comment: Are you talking about the Zeta function ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function

Comment: Yes, that must not be the comparison we're supposed to make because we haven't discussed zeta functions.